# Android Manifest Bug

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest

My app keeps crashing every time i load a certain activity given that it is error free.
the problem occurs in the manifest.xml as it keeps saying this error exists

```
 <activity android:name=".Fragment.MyAccountFragment"></activity>
```

the highlighted feedback is :MyAccountFragment must extend Android app activity

this is an excerpt of the Activity page:

```
class MyAccountFragment : Fragment() {

private val RC_SELECT_IMAGE = 2
private lateinit var selectedImageBytes: ByteArray
private var pictureJustChanged = false

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                         savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my_account_fragment, container, false)
```

Comment: Is "MyAccountFragment" An activity ?

Comment: @LenaBru Bru  yes it is

Comment: do you have a stack trace ?

Comment: @LenaBru im sorry,, I'm sort of a newbie in programming,, im not familiar with how that is done.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that `MyAccountFragment` is an Activity? That is, it says `class MyAccountFragment : Activity()` in the `.kt` file. It seems very likely that it extends `Fragment` instead.

Comment: @BenP. Just updated the excerpt from the activity file right now

Comment: looks like class MyAccountFragment : Fragment() is a fragment not activity, so remember the fragments are not declared on manifest. if you can add a stack trace or a complete error would be fine. and correct by reading the documentation
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments
that is absolute a fragment

Comment: @Antonio just enlightened myself on fragments with that article. Thanks

Comment: @LenaBru just learnt about stack trace and put it into use. Thanks

Comment: @BenP. kindly if its not a bother, give my question an upvote. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The header of your class file shows that it is a `Fragment` and not an `Activity`:

> ```
> class MyAccountFragment : Fragment()
> ```

Fragments do not need to be declared in the manifest at all, so you can just delete this line from your manifest:

> ```
> <activity android:name=".Fragment.MyAccountFragment"></activity>
> ```

Comment: Just ran my app, and it is now  ok.  Appreciated